A new look for the logged-out marketing homepage
Today we’re launching a refreshed logged-out marketing homepage on Stack Overflow, which replaces the last iteration we introduced in 2021. (For reference, here’s what this page looked like until today.)

If you were to review the explanatory post from that rollout, you would see a number of reasons that we believed it was necessary to update the page then. Most of the thinking from that iteration remains true: the vast majority of anonymous users are coming to question pages, so we’re maintaining awareness as our main objective for the homepage – people who may have never heard of Stack Overflow, and perhaps want to work with us, for us, or just learn more about us.
As you may know, the logged-out marketing homepage is different than the homepage for logged-in users. For both experiences, a homepage should serve a purpose – for logged-in users, perhaps it’s a jumping off point to their frequent actions, or where they can pick which new actions they’d like to try. But for logged-out users, it’s a touchpoint to see the breadth of the sites and products that they can experience here. It’s the first glimpse into the richness of this network.
Since 2021 we’ve been investing in stackoverflow.co as the de-facto place to learn about our services for businesses. A change you’ll see is that we’ve simplified how much “show & tell” we’re doing on that page for these services, in favor of a brief overview and a link to learn more over there.
You can see an image of the new logged-out marketing homepage below – for those logged-in you can visit stackoverflow.com?products to see it.

What’s new on the homepage:

We have created new sections for new products: OverflowAI and OverflowAPI are given prominent space.
The overall space given to other products (like Stack Overflow for Teams) is smaller.
We moved the link to the Q&A to a position of more prominence and highlighted it visually.
The whole page got a clean new design.

From a design perspective, we’ve brought the page more in line with how other pages on stackoverflow.com feel, so the contrast in experience between this and the rest of the site is less jarring.
I hope that community members will be pleased to see that we’ve made some changes to highlight the public platform. The link to the Q&A now appears fairly close to where your eye naturally falls on the page, and invites newcomers to visit the Q&A on Stack Overflow as almost the first call-to-action on the page.  This is as it should be, given the outsized role that the public platform plays in the success of this site (and company).
Finally, you may have seen there is other work around the logged-in homepage being done, so keep an eye out for further updates soon.  As always, if you have feedback on today’s rollout or the changes, feel free to leave them here. We will keep an eye here and will share them with the appropriate parties internally.
What do you think of the new logged-out marketing homepage? Is there something that you love there? What advice would you give us for future changes?

I haven't looked at this in detail, but I can at least see a link to questions (left sidebar, but also as "Visit the community"), so that's a big improvement. Looking at it a little bit more, it does, at the top, give a much better hint at what Stack Overflow, the site, is, rather than leaving me guessing about the purpose of the site I'd landed on, as the old homepage did. So, it's definitely an improvement. I know that's not the detailed evaluation you were probably hoping for, but it's all I have time for at the moment.

As long as "marketing" and "homepage" are in the same sentence you'll have been doing it wrong.

Reminder to people tempted to post answers in the comments that the answers section is down there ↓

At work, I more or less exclusively use Stack Overflow when logged out. I’ve only asked a tiny handful of questions, primarily because the vast majority of things I need to look up are either (1) already asked & answered, or (2) not a particularly good fit for a question. So, I’ve generally never needed to be logged in.
I’ll be honest - I avoid the “real” homepage as much as possible. When I land there, it’s annoying to try to find where the heck I should go to look for Q/A, and as such, I just have https://stackoverflow.com/questions bookmarked instead of https://stackoverflow.com since the homepage has generally been fairly useless to me.
The update is definitely better, but the “visit the community” button is de-emphasized compared to “log in” and “sign up”, when for me I don’t care about those - I know I’m not logged in and don’t intend to at work. They’re already prominent enough in the “Questions” section that I’d rather see the “hey go view, ask, and answer questions over here!” button more prominent. Plus, “view community” has never been intuitively “questions over here!” to me, at least.

I appreciate this answer specifically because it validates some speculation in my own.

I expect the logged-in users now do the same thing.

The most common way people end up on Stack Overflow is from a search result for some question they wanted to look up an answer for. It stands to reason that all these logged-out users are primarily interested in the Q&A section. They're not interested in SOfT, or the company. They could look that up separately, or check the About tab etc. if they were. The overwhelming majority of them are not going to go anywhere near the paid services you market, ever, and will be very annoyed at being marketed to.
Switching from a logged-out Q&A page to the new logged-out main page is certainly an improvement over how it was before. It's less visually jarring, certainly, since the left-hand sidebar is still there. But it's still IMO a user-hostile experience. Why should I have to "Visit the community" that I was literally just looking at? Just show me the Q&A.
Right now, by my quick SEDE queries, more than 90% of user accounts have never upvoted or downvoted. By previous queries, a big chunk have never asked or answered a question. There are about 1.0 questions and 1.5 answers per user, and I'm sure those numbers are considerably lower for accounts created within the past few months. I'm guessing you have similar stats internally. If you're interested in improving that "engagement" metric, maybe you could make the logged-out homepage promote the Tour and the Staging Ground as the first things, rather than, in order:

The place where the user most likely just was
A bunch of corporate services relevant to almost no visitors
The rest of the network (you already have the logged-out Stack Exchange homepage for that!)
A "work for us" link (why would anyone be interested?)
The Help Center, Meta (why are you directing people here, who are very likely not to have tried actually using the site and have only read one or two Q&As, to give feedback that will be completely ignorant of past business on Meta?), and more corporate stuff

That is: promote, you know, the things that are about understanding how to contribute to the site and then actually starting that process.

nit: I assume your SEDE queries don't account for anonymous votes cast by logged-in users... because (afaik) they can't.

To me, the section calling out Q&A looks like more of an ad than the rest of the page which are actually ads.
I don't understand why it seems so important to SO to not show literal questions and answers on a Q&A site's home page. Give people who reach it something to investigate.

FWIW, software.codidact.com looks almost identical for logged-in and logged-out users. The main codidact.com page gives you a grid promoting each community, while codidact.org is where promotional content lives for the platform and the Codidact Foundation.  (Also, instead of a 281KB "hero" image above the fold - which is scaled to less than half in each dimension for me - I get a 12KB svg file.) This organization strikes me as vastly more... respectful.

Bringing in codidact as an example would carry a lot more weight if that site 1: was actually active, and 2: didn't look like a 2010's clone of SO... And complaining about a 269KB size difference is equally... "2010".

Check out experiment 4 here which will look into more dynamic content for this page https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/400648/upcoming-sign-up-experiments-related-to-tags

i kinda have a whole answer there for experiment 4, ;)

Why are there filler / "placeholder" tiles in the communities section?
With over 170 communities, I'm sure we can think of a few to show off, there. You could even randomize which ones are shown.

(All the grayed-out tiles are not clickable)

shouldn't "You are here!" also be clickable, to take you to a page with actual content relevant to the stack you're on?

Also, it should be slightly more apparent what these things are if you want people to click them. As a new user, I probably wouldn't have a clue how the yellow cube differed from the red, green and blue cubes, or what the barely legible U&L was against the dark background.

It'd be great if site titles were provided here, even just for the larger tiles in the group. Right now it's a lot of empty space.

Randomizing is a great idea! Also like @KevinB's idea to take people through to /questions

I'd suggest showing trending questions. Something like- sort questions by upvotes received in the past two weeks (potentially feeding into a exponential decay function by how old the post that the vote was cast on is before summing if some Q&A are just always very popular, though that itself isn't a bad thing to show either...), and show the top 20 or something. What I hypothesize you'd end up seeing is... a bunch of stuff related to recent software bugs/issues. Stuff that is recent and relevant. Stuff that people might be looking for, and that there will be / would otherwise be a lot of newly posted duplicate questions about. Another way to get something similar could be to go by which questions have been used as the duplicate target of a lot of new questions recently.
The section listing other sites doesn't need to show SO. The reader is already there. I'd suggest showing other sites in the order of how much stuff has been migrated from SO to the other site, and the href going to the site's /help/on-topic page.


The whole page got a clean new design.

I disagree with that statement in particular, it got a trendy design.
You have to really go into full marketing mode it if you want to call that huge cloud of randomly placed icons clean. No it's noisy and it distracts from those beautiful, stylish and useful grey icons at the bottom of the page.
If the entire page would be like that, now that would be clean.

I think this is a significant improvement over the previous homepage. You know what would make it better?

These buttons should be straightforward links to the Active tab and friends. (Don't try for a cute "mini-list of questions": it won't work.) Bonus points if you can get the tab picker to display in exactly the same location as it does on the real homepage.
My thinking is: if this marketing homepage is just a homepage tab, and it's obvious how to get to the other tabs, the annoyance is minimised. (Also, logged-out users shouldn't be shown the Interesting tab, because you don't know their interests.)
It's almost a shame to lose this image: it's Corporate Memphis, sure, but I think it's actually art. However, usability is more important. Unless you're willing to put a heading ("Marketing?" There's precedent.) and the tab picker at the top of the page, something has to go.

As an aside, I'd recommend removing the Log in and Sign up buttons. They're already there at the top of the page: the duplication feels a bit desperate.
